# How do I get only two form fields to show instead of all 5 on initial page load? CSS

Tags: jquery, css

Here is the implementation:

http://jsfiddle.net/AdQfB/2/

If you notice, when you click 'Login' or 'Register' before entering anything, you should see a few fields disappear and re-appear respectively.

I would like for this page to display the view of just the two fields on the first load (rather than the current 5 it shows on first load), then when the user clicks the 'register' link, it shows the other 3 - for a total of 5.

How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning display block for input elements within sign_in div block, I think this is taking precedence over the input# css of display:none.

Make the input# css properties more specific be prefixing the selector with parent id:

Check the solution on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Chandu/AdQfB/8/
i.e.:
change the style:

```
input#confirm_pw, input#f_name, input#l_name {
    display: none;
}
```

to

```
div#sign_in input#confirm_pw, div#sign_in input#f_name, div#sign_in input#l_name {
    display: none;
}
```

Edit: Updated the solution to use a better fix.

Also apply a css style of display:block in the slideDown method (register button click event) as follows (JSFiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/Chandu/AdQfB/11/):

```
$("input#register").click(function(e) {    //This is for the registration form functionality
        console.log('register button clicked!');
        $("input#f_name").slideDown().prepend("<br /><br />").css({"display": "block"});
        $("input#l_name").slideDown().css({"display": "block"});
        $("input#confirm_pw").slideDown().css({"display": "block"});
        $("input#register").val('Submit');
        $("input#login").css({ 'color' : '#567603' });
        e.preventDefault();    
    });
```

Comment: This almost works. The only issue is that the `display: block` is really for layout issues. If you changed that on jsFiddle and ran it, you would see how it looks weird without a block display. I don't want the layout messed up.

Comment: This is the most elegant of all the solutions. Thanks. Nothing like a simple CSS selector change :)

Comment: Actually...almost there. When you click the 'Register' button, it further breaks the layout. Almost there Cybernate...please get it there. I really, really like this solution if you can get it there.

Comment: Updated the post along with jsFiddle URL. Please check

Answer (score 2):

You have to hide them when the site is loaded.

Try adding the following to the end of your jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("input#f_name").slideUp().css({"display": "hidden"});
     $("input#l_name").slideUp().css({"display": "hidden"});
     $("input#confirm_pw").slideUp();
});
```

Comment: I really like this solution. The only thing is that on the page load, you see the fields sliding up. How do I hide them without seeing the slideUp any at all? I tried just doing `input#f_name.css({"display" : "hidden"});` but that didn't work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#login").click();
});


<div id="sign_in">

    <form method="POST">
            <input id="f_name" type="text" value="First Name" required class="clearField curved" style="display:none;"/> <br />
            <input id="l_name" type="text" value="Last Name" required class="clearField curved" style="display:none;"/> <br />
            <input id="email" type="text" value="Email address" required class="clearField curved" /> <br />
            <input id="pw" type="password" value="Password" required class="clearField curved" /><br />    
            <input id="confirm_pw" type="password" value="Password" required class="clearField curved" style="display:none;"/><br />
        <div id="login_buttons">
            <input id="login" type="submit" value="Log in" class="curved"> 
            <input id="register" type="submit" value="Register" class="curved">
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: ?? Not quite sure how this will solve the problem. Ohh...I see what you are doing here. You are simulating a click function, once the document has loaded. Interesting solution. Wouldn't this submit an empty form though ?

Comment: Mithun P. I tried it, and I saw how it works. My issue is that they see the other fields being slid up on the page load. I want them to just see the two fields.

Comment: Add `display:none;` to those 'Register' screen fields, see http://jsfiddle.net/mithun/AdQfB/13/

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a "Login" click after page load, just by adding: `$("input#login").click();` at the end.